# Amount of Arrays created depends on input; How to debug?

Tags: java, arrays

I've been working on some USACO guide Bronze problems when I ran into two errors in one of my codes; a runtime error and a logic error.

The task, [Speeding Ticket](http://www.usaco.org/index.php?page=viewproblem2&cpid=568), inputs the miles traveled/speed limit and then the miles traveled/speed actually went and asks me to find the greatest number of mph that the speed limit was exceeded by.

The runtime error seemed to occur somewhere while asking for user input, but I've used the same method before and nothing happened then so I don't know where I'm going wrong.

As for the second one, thought it hasn't explicitly been said, I know this is an error in my code. The problem is, I actually don't know how to implement it. I know what I'd do if the number of pairs I needed to create was a fixed value, but here it depends on user input. So I'm stuck in that regard as well.
[Link to my code on replit](https://replit.com/@mathshanayapal/RemorsefulWorseBots#Main.java)

What I expected: 5
What I got:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVgXv.png)

Any help would be great!

Comment: The error message refers to Main.java line 11, where an attempt is made to parse an integer from an input. It even states `For input String "-Xlint"`, which is unlikely to be successfully parsed to an integer at all.

Comment: Ok I fixed the runtime error, thanks for all your help! Could someone help me figure out the second issue I have outlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `javac` call runs the compiler. The compiler found a *likely* bug in your code, but, your code is *technically* compilable. Just, weird. Hence, it tells you: Okay, I did compile your code, but, you should probably have a closer look at this thing because I really really doubt you meant what you wrote. That's what:

> Note: recompile with -Xlint for details

is about.

You are supposed to invoke `javac` a second time and add `-Xlint` (or just always add `-Xlint`) to tell the compiler to tell you far more about what it found.

Instead, you ran *your application* and passed `-Xlint` to *your application*. Your app parses all arguments as numbers, `-Xlint` obviously isn't a number, and therefore your app exits early because the exception caused by trying to parse `-Xlint` as number bubbled to the top.

I doubt replit is doing that. If so, you mail the replit staff and tell them they have a bug in their code runner system. There's nothing stack overflow, or you, can do about it - possibly you can work around it by ensuring that warning no longer happens.

However, it sounds vastly more likely that *you* are running the stuff in your screenshot image. In which case, don't pass `-Xlint` to `java` - you pass that to `javac`.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense, (and thanks for explaining that error I had no idea what it meant!) However, now it's saying no source files when I try to pass -Xlint...

Comment: You rerun the same `javac` statement as you pasted, but put `-Xlint` in between `javac` and `-classpath`.